# Python library with config file

Tags: python, containers, config

I would like to gather many libraries I have made while working on my projects in some kind of container, so that I can easily use any of them in future projects of mine. It is pretty clear to me how to do this, except one part.

I am assuming that every service will have its own config file (for instance, the `Cache` service, will have a config file with cache host and port, and so on). Now the problem is: when I want to use this container in an arbitrary project I will have to make assumptions about the project directory structure to know where to find these config files.

For instance, one might assume that on the same path of my library there is a `config` folder where I will find the config files of my services. However, this might conflict with the project's directory structure (i.e. the project might already have its own `config` directory for instance).

So, all in all, my question is: is there a safe, standard way to ship a library which might assume to find some config files someplace, or for which example config files are shipped along with the library itself?

Comment: What do you mean by "container" here?

Comment: `s/by "container" here//` I mean seriously, I haven't understood a thing from your question.

Comment: I mean in general a singleton to which services can be registered and through wich services can be instantiated (for instance, I have a `Cache` service, a `CommunicationChannel` service and so on). If this is not clear enough, please let me know of what I should be more specific about.

Comment: @zmo I see, I'd be glad to make myself more clear if you can point out what you are missing from my explanation.

Comment: I am sorry if I was not clear enough, I am refferring to `container` in the following sense: http://best-practice-software-engineering.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/patterns/container.html

Comment: Typically, you'd have the library or module or whatever be capable of receiving configuration externally so it's not coupled to a filesystem layout or really, a file at all.

Comment: This all sounds very opinion-based, but in projects I've build before I've included a `config.py` module in each library that handled individual set up on its own. You may have to build an adapter to modify this to use the same library across multiple packages, though. See [this pet project](https://bitbucket.org/darimart/find-paperwork/src) which is a little tk app designed to look up archived PDFs.

Comment: Although I'm not active on that site, programmers.SE may be a better home for this question, since it's talking about nebulous best practices. The only three ways I can interpret this question here would be A) a request for a 3rd party module to handle config paths, which is off-topic, B) an opinion poll on where best to save configs, which is off-topic or C) a serious discussion on all the possible use-cases of config files, which is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

well, you should not keep config files, or anything that you want to modify along with code in python (or actually in any language). Each OS have folders for that purpose.

Either it's system wide, and on Unix it's `/etc` or it's for an user it's in `~/.config`. You have  the`Library` folders for OSX, and I'm sure there's something alike for windows beyond `\Windows\SYSTEM32` .

What that means is that the path to your configuration files shall not be considered relative to your code at any point. Never. Ever.

You can include some *assets* in a python package, using the [`MANIFEST.in`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/distutils/sourcedist.html#the-manifest-in-template) but, as it'll be within your python package, you shall assume you won't have rights to write where it'll be (installed by admin, ran by user).

You can also specify some of those assets to install at specific places using `setup.py`'s [`data_files`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files) directive, which will be installed relatively to `sys.prefix`.

Common practice is to provide configuration files examples using a link from the documentation, or better generate those files when starting the application.

Also, another trend for desktops, is to use the [XDG directory specification](https://github.com/srstevenson/xdg), to decide where to look for, or where to place your configuration files.

To sum it up:

- make a list of default paths your code expects to find the configuration,
- make it possible to specify manually at command line the path to the configuration `python foo.py --config bar.ini`
- write a feature for your tool to generate the configuration (with a series of questions)
- deploy your default configurations to standard places (XDG paths, $prefix/etc…)

Comment: Windows has `%APPDATA%` and `%LOCALAPPDATA%` which resolve to `"C:\users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\"` and `"C:\users\<username>\AppData\Local\"` respectively. The latter should be used for local installations, while the former is shared among other machines that domain user may use.

Comment: hm… interesting… I'd be curious to know why I got  for just telling what's considered common good practice.

Comment: Me too. I don't see anything particularly bad about this answer, except perhaps that it's answering an unanswerable question. The question should be closed as off-topic, but the answer does its best to address the question in as much scope as possible.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ well…

Comment: I agree, I don't think you deserved a downvote (upvoting to make up for it). Apart from this, you have really listed the general way to do this but I was expecting something more like "best practices" to ship a library along with its config files. For instance, like Laravel and Django libraries have config files and expect to find them in a certain path. Of course maybe in those cases we are more talking about "frameworks" than "libraries". But maybe I am just confused.